# Avoid code duplication if what changes is one argument type only

Tags: go

As you can see these functions differ only in `keys []int` and `keys []*int` (and in name).

```golang
func (db *myDB) QueryWithKeys(keys []int) ([]*models.Player) {
    var players = make([]*models.Player, len(keys))
  _ := db.Model(&players).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(keys)).Select()
  // several other equal code here
    return players
}

func (db *myDB) QueryWithPointerKeys(keys []*int) ([]*models.Player) {
    var players = make([]*models.Player, len(keys))
    _ := db.Model(&players).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(keys)).Select()
  // several other equal code here
    return players
}
```

**Is there a way to avoid this code duplication?**